# #include header with C declarations in an assembly file without errors?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, include, x86

I have an assembly file (`asm.S`) which needs a constant `#define`'d in a C header file (`c_decls.h`).  The header file contains C function declarations in addition to the `#define` I want.  Unfortunately, `gcc` barfs when trying to compile the assembly file.  For example,

**c_decls.h**

```
#ifndef __c_decls_h__
#define __c_decls_h__

#define I_NEED_THIS 0xBEEF
int foo(int bar);

#endif
```

**asm.S**

```
#include "c_decls.h"

.globl main
main:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    movl $I_NEED_THIS, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

**Output**

> > gcc -m32 asm.S
>   c_decls.h: Assembler messages:
>   c_decls.h:6: Error: junk '(int bar)' after expression
>   c_decls.h:6: Error: suffix or operands invalid for 'int'

Is there a way to `#include` a C header file that contains function declarations in an assembly file?  (Changing the header or moving/redefining the `#define` is not an option.)

Comment: (Changing the header or moving/redefining the #define is not an option.)

Seeing as you've disqualified the most reasonable option, I'd say you're out of luck. :-)

Comment: Considering that the header is invoking undefined behavior (by using a name that begins with double-underscore as its multiple-inclusion guard), I think you should reconsider the requirement of not changing it. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `-dM` option for `cpp` to get just the #defines out of your header files, and include that file instead.

```
cpp -dM c_decls.h > bare_c_decls.h
```

Now include `bare_c_decls.h` in your .S file.  And if you can't change the #include in the .S file, generate the bare header files in another directory, and put that include path on your compiler/assembler command line, ahead of everything else.

And finally, you can wrap this all up in a makefile so your "bare" header files are generated automatically.

Comment: Simple `-dM` doesn't work for me. It returns nothing. `-E -dM` dumps all defines, including one which is defined in a header. There only inconvenience that there are more than 700 defines in the list.

Comment: What version of cpp are you using?  (Note the question is related to gcc)

Comment: It's GNU GCC, `arm-none-eabi-g++ (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 4.9.3 20150529 (release)`

Comment: @user3124812: You probably ran `gcc -dM` rather than `cpp -dM`.  You *should* use `gcc -E -dM` with all other compile options you normally use, to make sure all `#ifdef`s in your headers get the same pre-defined macros.  (e.g. maybe you have `#ifdef __AVX__` in a header, and define something differently if building on an x86 target with `-mavx` vs. without.)  So I'd recommend not using `cpp` directly.

Answer (score 11):

That's simle:
In your .S file use

```
#define __ASSEMBLY__
```

In your .C file use

```
#undef __ASSEMBLY__
```

Then in .h file place condition

```
       #ifdef __ASSEMBLY__
                  // here declarations only for assembler
       #else
                  // here only for C
       #endif
                  // and here - defines suitable for both
```

Comment: Header should be included with 'C' like include, `#include my_defs.h`, not 'ASM' like `.include my_defs.h`. In last case `#ifdef`, `#else`, `#endif` will be ignored by asm parser. Just stumble over this...

Comment: `gcc foo.S` already pre-defines `__ASSEMBLER__` to 1.  So you can just protect all your C-only stuff with `#ifndef __ASSEMBLER__`