# Including a header file in a .S to get some struct size

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, struct, arm

I am trying to compile a mixed C-code and an assembly-code project, while trying to share information between .S file and some header file, I ran into a problem.

I have created two files, as follows:

asm.S:

```
#include "common.h"

.space SOME_STRUCT_SIZE
.word SOME_MAGIC

.globl main
b start

start:
   ; ... code here
```

common.h:

```
struct someStruct {
    int data;
};

#define SOME_STRUCT_SIZE sizeof(struct someStruct)
#define SOME_MAGIC 0x12345678
```

When trying to compile the .S file (`arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o asm asm.S`), I get error messages indicating the assembler is trying to assemble the .h file, and obviously fails on the struct definition.

```
common.h: Assembler messages:
common.h:2: Error: bad instruction 'int data'
```

Is it possible to force the pre-processor to statically create both defines and insert them in a way that the assembly code can use?

Comment: the problem is that `sizeof` needs to be compiled by the c compiler. The preprocessor is simply a text replacing machine

Comment: I understand, I am looking for different ways to implement this

Comment: I think this might be useful for the defines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928238/include-header-with-c-declarations-in-an-assembly-file-without-errors

Comment: Your `.space` and `.word` directives can be just as easily implemented on the C side. You will have more issues addressing fields of your struct anyway.

Comment: You are wanting the assembler to include C code and to assemble that but that's the job of the C compiler as @pm100 states. That's not what gcc does so it can't be done.

Comment: Seems to me you need to write a c program that emits a header file that is in the form that yr assembler can accept. Should take 10 mins to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented what @pm100 suggested, and it worked out just fine.

common_bare_gen.c:

```
#include "common.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void){
    FILE *common_bare_fp;   
    common_bare_fp = fopen("common_bare.h", "w");

    fprintf(common_bare_fp, "#define SOME_STRUCT_SIZE 0x%08x\n", SOME_STRUCT_SIZE);
    fprintf(common_bare_fp, "#define SOME_MAGIC 0x%08x\n", SOME_MAGIC);
    fclose(common_bare_fp);
}
```

In asm.S I changed:

```
#include "common_bare.h"
```

And added two commands to compile and execute `common_bare_gen` in my Makefile.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

This may seem convoluted but it may also achieve the same goal. You could create a *C* macro that simply creates `#defines` for strings and values that may need to propagate to an assembler header. You can create a function that uses these macros to generate the defines. You can then use `-S` feature of *GCC* to output the assembly and then use *GREP* to sift out the defines that were generated dumping them to an include file that can be used by your assembly (.S) file.

File `gnuasm.h`:

```
#define GNUASM_DEFINE_STR(SYMBOL, STR) \
    __asm__  ("#define " SYMBOL " " #STR);

#define GNUASM_DEFINE_VAL(SYMBOL, VALUE) \
    __asm__  ("#define " SYMBOL " %a0" :: "n"(VALUE));
```

The trick in the macro is to use the **asm** directive to emit the defines. This will cause them to appear in the generated `.s` file. `GNUASM_DEFINE_STR` can be used at global scope but for `GNUASM_DEFINE_VAL` to work you'll need to put it in a dummy function.

Your `common.h` would remain unchanged:

```
struct someStruct {
    int data;
};

#define SOME_STRUCT_SIZE sizeof(struct someStruct)
#define SOME_MAGIC 0x12345678
```

Create a dummy *C* file (it doesn't need to be linked with your project) that includes `common.h` and the `gnuasm.h` macros file with a dummy function. In this case I'll call it `common-defs.c`:

```
#include "gnuasm.h"
#include "common.h"

/* Dummy function used to generate the defines we need */
void common_defines(void)
{
    GNUASM_DEFINE_STR("SOME_STRING", "some string");
    GNUASM_DEFINE_VAL("SOME_STRUCT_SIZE", SOME_STRUCT_SIZE);
    GNUASM_DEFINE_VAL("SOME_MAGIC", SOME_MAGIC);

    return;
}
```

This file is meant to be compiled and for the assembly output to be generated like this:

```
gcc common-defs.c -c -S
```

This produces a file `common-defs.s`. This is the assembly code that represents the *C* code. All the defines we emitted can then be parsed out with *GREP* and then output into an include file that our assembly file can include:

```
grep "#define" common-defs.s >common.inc
```

Now in our `asm.S` file you can include this at the top:

```
#include "common.inc"
```

The generated `common.inc` file would appear something like:

```
    #define SOME_STRING "some string"
    #define SOME_STRUCT_SIZE 4
    #define SOME_MAGIC 305419896
```

---

When using `struct` another useful thing for assembly are the offsets of member variables. Those could be generated like this:

```
GNUASM_DEFINE_VAL("SOME_STRUCT_DATA_OFFSET", offsetof(struct someStruct, data));
```