# How to print the value of a complicated macro at compilation time in C language?

Tags: c, macros

I am not quite sure whether it is impossible to print a compicated-macro value at compilation time in C language.
My macro is Like below:

```
#define ADDR_START1        0x0001
#define SIZE1              0x1000 
#define ADDR_START2        START1 + SIZE1
#define SIZE2              0x2000 
#define ADDR_START3        START2 + SIZE2
#define SIZE3              0x3000
#define ADDR_RESERVED      0xFFFF - (ADDR_START3 + SIZE3)
```

Now, in order to get to know the remaining address size at compilation time, how can I print the value of "ADDR_RESERVED"?
If the value is unavailable, is it because any calculation process cannot be done during compilation time?

Comment: Printing the value may be difficult, but you can conditionally abort compilation using `#if` and `#error` directives.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I show the value of a #define at compile-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562074/how-do-i-show-the-value-of-a-define-at-compile-time)

Comment: @mnistic: No, that is for a situation that involves mere macro replacement, not arithmetic.

Comment: A way to do this with GCC and Clang is to use the macro in an `asm` construct as the value of an “immediate” operand, which puts its value into the assembly source code. Then compile with the `-S` option to generate the assembly code and use `grep` or a similar tool to extract the line. There is some information about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334646/including-a-header-file-in-a-s-to-get-some-struct-size/47339218#47339218), although there may be better answers.

Comment: I am usually using solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979565/how-can-i-print-the-result-of-sizeof-at-compile-time-in-c), if it is about some numerical value.

Comment: Modern IDEs can expand macros. This includes everything Clangd-based (e.g. VSC with Clangd extension) and the latest VS too.

Answer (score 1):

The language doesn't provide a way to see the intermediate output of the preprocessor, but the compiler might. For instance, for gcc, the `-E` flag tells it to just run the preprocessor.  This will result in a few billion lines of extraneous output from the header files, so you'll probably want to filter those out.

For gcc, this will do the trick (for a source file named "filename.c"):

```
gcc -dI -E filename.c | awk '/^# /{skip=1} !skip{print} /^# .*"filename.c"/{skip=0}'
```

In addition to the `-E` flag, we pass `-dI`, which leaves the `#include` lines in place (in addition to expanding them). The `awk` command then filters out everything that doesn't come from "filename.c". It won't actually do arithmetic, since it's the compiler that handles that step, but it'll expand everything.

```
$ cat filename.c
#include <stdio.h>

#define F(A,B) A+B

F(32,10)

$ gcc -dI -E filename.c | awk '/^# /{skip=1} !skip{print} /^# .*"filename.c"/{skip=0}'
#include <stdio.h>



32+10
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MikeCAT's suggestion I tried the testing code below and it works fine:

```
#if ADDR_RESERVED < 0
#error "no remaining space..."
#endif
```

Despite no value being printed, the solution solved my needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
admittedly, this is ultra brute force :

 echo '

#define ADDR_START1        0x0001
#define SIZE1              0x1000
#define ADDR_START2        START1 + SIZE1
#define SIZE2              0x2000
#define ADDR_START3        START2 + SIZE2
#define SIZE3              0x3000
#define ADDR_RESERVED      0xFFFF - (ADDR_START3 + SIZE3)' |
```

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN { FS="(^[#]define)?[() \t]+"
>               RS="[ \t]*\n[ \t]*" 
> } sub("^", sprintf("%16d ", 5 < NF \
> ? +$3 + (-1)^("-"==$4) * (__[$5] + (-1)^("-"==$6) + __[$7]) \
> : __[$2]=__[substr($2, index($2,"_")+1)]= NF==3              \
>                   ? +$3 : __[$3] + (-1)^("-"==$4) * __[$5]))^_'
> ```

```
               1 #define ADDR_START1        0x0001
            4096 #define SIZE1              0x1000
            4097 #define ADDR_START2        START1 + SIZE1
            8192 #define SIZE2              0x2000
           12289 #define ADDR_START3        START2 + SIZE2
           12288 #define SIZE3              0x3000
           40957 #define ADDR_RESERVED      0xFFFF - (ADDR_START3 + SIZE3)
```

and the hex-version matches expectations :

```
 0x               1 #define ADDR_START1        0x0001
 0x            1000 #define SIZE1              0x1000
 0x            1001 #define ADDR_START2        START1 + SIZE1
 0x            2000 #define SIZE2              0x2000
 0x            3001 #define ADDR_START3        START2 + SIZE2
 0x            3000 #define SIZE3              0x3000
 0x            9FFD #define ADDR_RESERVED      0xFFFF - (ADDR_START3 + SIZE3)
```

it's "algorithmic" in the sense it's actually reading variable values and doing math on them, but it's also brute force for hard-coding in the parenthesis and not having any ability to parse nested algebraic expressions