# gnu GAS use stdio.h in asm and compile 32 bit on 64 bit host

Tags: assembly, x86, c-preprocessor, 32bit-64bit, gnu-assembler

I want to compile the following asm.S file

```
#include <stdio.h>
.global _start
.text
message_text:
  call program
str: .string "hello world"
  .equ len, (. - str)

_start:
  jmp message_text
program:
  call puts@PLT
```

I have tried `gcc -m32 asm.S` as well as `gcc -m32 asm.S -fPIC` and a litany of other things but I keep running into errors such as

> /usr/include/stdio.h:847: Error: no such instruction: extern void ...

What am I doing wrong?

I get that the preprocessor is just inserting the header into the asm file and so the assembler is getting erroring out b/c C function prototypes are not assembly instructions. However I have been able to use `#include <asm/unistd.h>` and `#include <syscall.h>` with success. So why won't stdio.h work?

As an aside, I tried commenting out the header and just keeping the line `call puts@PLT` and was able to compile via

> ```
> as --32 -o output.o asm.S
> ld -m elf_i386 -o output output.o -lc
> ```

However now, when I try `./output` I get

> no such file or dirctory: ./output

despite *output* showing up in `ls` and if I run `file output` I get

> output: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /usr/bin/libc.so.1, not stripped

If instead I do

> ```
> as --32 -o output.o asm.S
> ld -m elf_i386 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o output -lc output.o
> ```

I can run the resulting binary. But again, this is if I remove `#include <stdio.h>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stdio.h` is a C header with C syntax, not just C preprocessor stuff.  In asm you don't need C prototypes or variable declarations; in GAS any undeclared symbol is assumed to be `extern` so you can just `call puts@plt` without any other directives.  (Unlike NASM where you would need `extern puts`, which is different syntax from C so the C header wouldn't help anyway.)

A few C headers like `<asm/unistd.h>` contain *only* `#if` and `#define` preprocessor directives, and can be included in `.S` files as well.  Most headers can't, although the Linux kernel's `asm/*.h` typically can.

Standard headers *could* have been written to use `#ifndef __ASSEMBLY__` around C specific parts, which would have been useful for headers like `<fcntl.h>` which have constants like `O_RWDR` and `O_TRUNC` as well as C prototypes, but they weren't.

[The stdio API predates the C preprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519263/why-does-cs-fopen-take-a-const-char-as-its-second-argument/51264235#51264235), which is why it unfortunately uses strings like `fopen(name, "r+")` instead of ORing constants.  So this isn't necessary or useful on `stdio.h`.

See also:

- [Opening file modes in x86 assembly Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71558966/opening-file-modes-in-x86-assembly-linux) - how to extract `O_*` macro constants from standard headers with `grep`, to make something you can `#include` in a `.S`.
- [#include header with C declarations in an assembly file without errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928238/include-header-with-c-declarations-in-an-assembly-file-without-errors) - in general you can extract just the defines with `gcc -E -dM` on a header, e.g. to get `O_RDONLY` and other constants for use with system calls.

---

BTW, your `jmp` / `call` trick to push a string address looks like shellcode.  But you can't `call puts@plt` in shellcode because the relative offset from a stack buffer to that PLT entry will be randomized.

Or perhaps it's just a hacky way to make 32-bit PIC code, in which case it's compact-ish but inefficient: defeats return-address prediction.  (Mismatched call/ret).  Look at how gcc or `clang -O2 -m32 -fPIC` compiles C code, getting an address for the GOT into a register with `call`; note that `call next_instruction` (relative offset of `0`) is [special cased](http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/04/ras-microbenchmarks/#call0) to not count for return-address prediction on most CPUs.  See *[Reading program counter directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599968/reading-program-counter-directly)*

This is clang `-O2 -m32 -fPIE` output from the [Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:5,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:5,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:5),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%7B%0A++++return+puts(%22hello%22)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1500,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%271%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-m32+-O2+-fPIE%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50.10752688172043,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:49.89247311827957,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) with necessary directives kept, unnecessary ones manually removed.  (Godbolt's directives filter will normally filter everything, assuming that you know which ones are needed.)

This is the standard way to get a static address into a register in position-independent 32-bit code.  (Nevermind that it's a `main` so it returns instead of calling `exit`.  Or `_exit` or a raw system call, but don't do that in programs that use stdio functions; that wouldn't flush stdout if there was buffered output left, e.g. because of writing to a pipe.)

```
        .text
        .globl  main                            # -- Begin function main
main:
        pushl   %ebx
        subl    $8, %esp
        calll   .L0$pb
.L0$pb:
        popl    %ebx
.Ltmp0:
        addl    $_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+(.Ltmp0-.L0$pb), %ebx   # pointer to the GOT
        leal    .L.str@GOTOFF(%ebx), %eax           # .L.str address relative to GOT
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        calll   puts@PLT
.Ltmp1:
        addl    $8, %esp
        popl    %ebx
        retl                 # note that _start can't ret, it has to call exit.

#   .section        .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1  # clang used this
    .section        .rodata                      # a human would normally do this
.L.str:
        .asciz  "hello"
```

This two-step calculation getting a GOT base is not necessary since we don't use the global offset table for anything else; it's just the compiler's choice of reference anchor for position-independent code in 32-bit mode (where RIP-relative addressing isn't available).  We could `add $.L.str - .L0$pb, %ebx` after the `pop`.  And we could have used `%eax` so we didn't have to save/restore EBX.

It's a lot simpler to use position-dependent code in 32-bit so you can just `push $.L.str`, or to use 64-bit code where you'd `lea .L.str(%rip), %rdi` ; `call puts@plt`.

---

> `interpreter /usr/bin/libc.so.1`

There's your problem.  That path probably doesn't exist, and certainly isn't the runtime dynamic linker `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` (aka ELF interpreter).  Use `gcc -m32 -nostartfiles` if you want to write your own `_start`, but have it make a dynamically linked executable with libc and the right ELF interpreter.  (Use `gcc -v` to see what args it passes to the assembler and linker).

IDK why your `ld` would have a weird default like that; usually the default interpreter path is right for 32-bit mode but wrong for 64-bit executables.

See also *[Assembling 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system (GNU toolchain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain)* re: build commands and `_start` vs. `main`.

Note that **calling libc functions from your own `_start` only works in a dynamically linked executable** because libc uses dynamic linker hooks to get its init functions called before your `_start` runs.  If you'd used `-static`, code in `puts` would crash.

Comment: Nice thorough answer, yeah the shellcode style to put the string on the stack was just so I could whip up a quick example to try and call puts. Really was wanting to see what all could be done w/ including c headers in the asm file.

Comment: @skyfire: For a quick example, Linux PIE/PIC allows text relocations, so you could have just used `push $string` and let the dynamic linker take care of fixing up that relocation when the process is executed.  As for what you can do without C headers, literally anything.  Although some things require scraping information from them, or hard-coding the same constants, to get the right constants for APIs like POSIX `open(2)` or `mmap(2)`.

Comment: would it be `push $str` or `push str`? still getting my head around GAS syntax.

Comment: @skyfire: You want to push the address, so in AT&T it would be `push $str`.  If you wrote `pushl str`, it would load 4 bytes from memory (with a 32-bit absolute addressing mode) and push that.  In GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix`, it would be `push OFFSET string`.  In NASM, it would be `push str` (the address) vs. `push dword [str]` (the data), because NASM works differently from GAS.